# Отправить JSON в чистом виде через GET запрос

Tags: php, api, get, request, backend

Есть Api, на который нужно отравить GET запрос  с двумя переменными: просто строкой и массивом с массивами в JSON'e, причем JSON должен быть чистым в виде {<какие-то данные>}, без всяких перфомартирований и перекодировок. Пробовали отправлять через встроенный http client в yii2, через guzzle, curl и file_get_contents, результат один и тот же - '{' символы в JSON переменной "перекодируются" в набор символов, который api сервер отказывается принимать. Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Так в GET запрос по-любому строковые данные должны идти. Для этого JSON и используется - что его просто и без заморочек, стандартными методами, можно конвертировать в строку перед отправкой. Причем, с правильным экранированием.
Иной вариант - кодировать в URL: JSON `{"a": 1}` станет `%7B%22a%22%3A%201%7D` только какова выгода от такого подхода, мне не очень понятно.

Comment: Вот в этом и проблема, что все известные мне и упомянутые средства  %7B%22a%22%3A%201%7 в такой формат JSON переводят, а нужно в чистом

Comment: Ну нет такого "чистого" формата. Все, что передается параметрами GET запроса, кодируется предваритально в URL-safe формат, который можно передать через URL. Покажите, что за API используется. Есть документация какая-нибудь?

Comment: для передачи json на сервер нужно пользоваться post-запросом. возвращать json может и get-запрос. не писал код на php, наверное нужно что-то вроде [такого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Comment: @АлексейОбухов ну насчёт «нужно» решаем не мы, а авторы упомянутого API, мало ли какие извращения им в голову пришли)

Comment: @smellyshovel https://data.egov.kz/pages/samples , в имеющихся малочисленных примерах используется как раз-таки в "чистом" формате

Comment: может тогда что-то вроде [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347505/how-to-pass-a-json-object-as-a-parameter-with-an-url) поможет

Comment: Это просто кривое описание. Нормально они принимают urlencode https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaHWa.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалось решить проблему путем прогонки параметров через rawurldecode(), перед присоединением их к url, и добавлением  параметра JSON_UNESCAPED_LINE_TERMINATORS при переформатировании в JSON